# Temporal Expression library in .NET

Tags: .net, expression, temporal

Does anyone know of a library to handle events and recurring events likes the temporal expression libraries that exist for ruby like Runt (http://runt.rubyforge.org/) or TExp (http://texp.rubyforge.org/). Those libraries are perfect for what I need, but I need something in the >.NET Framework.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DDay.ical](http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.iCal/) includes more than what you're looking for (it's a full iCal library), but the ability to materialize recurring events is part of the package.

Comment: This is peftect. I got so caught up with the temporal expressions, i didnt think to look for iCal support instead.

Answer (score 3):

Would Quartz.NET fit the bill?

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/features.html

Comment: This looks like a great library, but i think the DDay library gives me a bit more. I didn't even think about iCal support, but it would give me some flexibility. Thanks for the link though

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source temporal expressions library written in c# on [github](https://github.com/zacg/TemporalToolkit)